# React Native Webview won't display

Tags: react-native, webview

I imported webview and added it to my component like so:

```
import { useState, useContext, useRef } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,

} from "react-native";
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
export default function HTML_CSS_JS_Editor(props) {
  return (
    <View>
            <WebView
              originWhitelist={['*']}
              source={{ html: '<h1>Hello World</h1>' }}
            />
            <Text>Dummy Text</Text>
          </View>
          
  );
}
```

The string "Hello World" isn't rendered - nothing shows up! When I use the example from the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) I get the following error message: "Text strings must be rendered within a text component":

```
import { useState, useContext, useRef } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,

} from "react-native";
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
export default function HTML_CSS_JS_Editor(props) {
  return (
    <View>
       <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} style={{ flex: 1 }} />;
            <Text>Dummy Text</Text>
          </View>
          
  );
}
```

I tried everything I could think of to solve this issue. Almighty ChatGpt has no clue how to deal with this issue. package.json shows I have the latest version installed: "react-native-webview": "^11.26.0"

Any suggestions?